# Clone Azure Services to New Environments

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-stream-analytics

We have already released stream analytics service and data factory to prod. Now we have to clone same setup in another new environment please let me know how to achieve this in best ways

Answer (score 0):

You can redeploy an Azure Stream Analytics job by exporting the Azure Resource Manager template.

Before you can export a template, you must first open an existing Stream Analytics job in Visual Studio Code.

To export a job to a local project, locate the job you wish to export in the Stream Analytics Explorer in the Azure portal. From the Query page, select Open in Visual Studio. Then select Visual Studio Code.

[image]

The next step is to compile the job script to an Azure Resource Manager template. Before you compile the script, ensure that your job has at least one input and one output configured. If no input or output is configured, you need to configure the input and output first.

1. In Visual Studio Code, navigate to your job's `Transformation.asaql` file.

[image]

2. Right-click the `Transformation.asaql` file and select ASA: Compile Script from the menu.
3. Notice that a Deploy folder appears in your Stream Analytics job workspace.
4. Explore the `JobTemplate.json` file, which is the Azure Resource Manager template used to deploy.

Next, complete the Azure Resource Manager template parameters file.

1. Open the JobTemplate.parameters.json file located in the Deploy folder of your Stream Analytics job workspace in Visual Studio Code.
2. Notice that the input and output keys are null. Replace the null values with the actual access keys for your input and output resources.
3. Save the parameters file.

You're ready to deploy your Azure Stream Analytics job using the Azure Resource Manager templates you generated in the previous section.

In a PowerShell window, run the following command. Be sure to reaplce the **ResourceGroupName**, **TemplateFile**, and **TemplateParameterFile** with your actual resource group name, and the complete file paths to the `JobTemplate.json` and `JobTemplate.parameters.json` files in the Deploy Folder of your job workspace.

```
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName "<your resource group>" -TemplateFile "<path to JobTemplate.json>" -TemplateParameterFile "<path to JobTemplate.parameters.json>"
```

Source: [Export an Azure Stream Analytics job Azure Resource Manager template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/resource-manager-export)